# Android not uploading image/bitmap to server

Tags: php, android, image, upload

I am able to pick an image from my gallery, and update a ImageView, so all of that is good. When I click on the submit button, I print the filename to the console and this is what is printed. `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20191127_190337_870.jpg`

Now, lets get into code.

```
public class SaveStashItem extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String > {
    Context myContext;

    String result;

    public SaveStashItem(Context context) {
        myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



        try {
            // set parameters and execute

            URL url = new URL(Constants.API_ADD_ITEM);
            Map<String,Object> params1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            params1.put(Constants.FILE_NAME, getPath(filepath));


            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params1.entrySet()) {
                if (postData.length() != 0){postData.append('&');}
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
            }
            byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

            //Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            Constants.logInformation(TAG, "Server Response is: " + total.toString(), 

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, las I said before, I am successfully getting the path for the image that I selected. I send that to the server as a POST and then get it like this.

```
$fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['imagePath1']['name']);

echo json_encode($fileinfo);
```

I will get the basename and filename as empty.

```
11-28 07:55:28.148 14722-14722/I/System.out: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20191127_190337_870.jpg
11-28 07:55:28.391 14722-14891/I/MyStash: Server Response is: {"basename":"","filename":""}
```

Why are these empty? Is the POST not correct?

Comment: @blackapps thanks but the problem isn't the PHP code at this point. The filename is empty during transfer, so im not sending a file with my post. That's the problem... Not the PHP code

Comment: I already thougth that you were not sending the file itself. But then still we need to know the php code that receives the parameters as that code complains that parametes are empty.

Comment: @blackapps $fileinfo receives it

Comment: Yes but your php code echos()'s "basename":"","filename":"" So show your code.

Comment: @blackapps I'm echoing fileinfo dude. Look at above, I post it

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Oversaw. There is no "basename" in your Android upload code nor a "filename" so you did not show what you put in.

Comment: @blackapps definitely not the reason my man. but thanks for your time. If you celebrate, have a great thanksgiving. I advise you to look into transferring of files/images in java. those get populated from the request... in my request, i am sending the filePath for the uploaded image. $_FILES() is supposed to populate those based on the imagepath that is sent. the issue is within the android code, i just need to find it. ill dig else where/look up tutorials. im sure its been done before

Comment: Yes i do it every day so i can help you i think. But if you do not post reproducable code helping is impossible.